# SQL Developer pivot with unknown number of values into one column

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I've been trying to figure out how to use the pivot function in SQL Developer for this one query I'm trying to do. I didn't find anything to really help me from previous posts so I was hoping someone could help me out.

A small section of the data that I need to select currently looks like this:

```
| ID | NAME | COUNTRY | STATE | DATE |  TYPE  | AMOUNT |
+----+------+---------+-------+------+--------+--------+
|  1 | John | U.S.    | TX    |  345 | Red    |     76 |
|  1 | John | U.S.    | TX    |  345 | Blue   |    357 |
|  2 | Alex | U.S.    | CO    |  654 | Red    |    231 |
|  2 | Alex | U.S.    | CO    |  654 | Black  |     90 |
|  2 | Alex | U.S.    | CO    |  654 | Blue   |    123 |
|  2 | Alex | U.S.    | CO    |  654 | Red    |    456 |
|  1 | John | U.S.    | TX    |  345 | Gold   |     60 |
|  1 | John | U.S.    | TX    |  345 | Silver |     70 |
```

I need to have each different type as its own column so that the above becomes:

```
| ID | NAME | COUNTRY | STATE | DATE | RED | BLUE | BLACK  | OTHER  |
+----+------+---------+-------+------+-----+------+--------+--------+
|  1 | John | U.S.    | TX    |  345 |  76 |  357 | (null) | 130    |
|  2 | Alex | U.S.    | CO    |  654 | 687 |  123 | 90     | (null) |
```

In my data, I don't know how many 'Other' colours there are, or what they all are (but there's definitely a finite number of them)

I appreciate any help anyone can offer me with this.

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: how much data do you have? it might be easier to do in excel if only a few 1000s...

Comment: (**1**) Is it a coincidence that `DATE` values are consistent for each name? (**2**) You want a **single** "OTHER" column for all colors you have not explicitly listed, right?

Comment: @bluefeet My apologies. This is in Oracle.

Comment: @deathApril There's A LOT of data. Much more than a few thousand.

Comment: @PM 77-1 (1)It's not a coincidence, that will always be the case.
(2) That's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not specify what version of Oracle you are using.  If you are using Oracle 11g, then you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select *
from
(
  select id, name, country, state, "DATE", amount,
    case 
      when type in ('Red', 'Blue', 'Black') then type
      else 'Other' end type
  from yt
) 
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for type in ('Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Other')
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f067/1)

Comment: I'm using Oracle3. Your pivot function method seems like it would be very efficient, but unfortunately doesn't work for me. But thank you!

Comment: @DrNerj no way! There is no way you are running Oracle 3! Oracle three came out in 81. The big feature for that is Commitable Transactions. Your version of ORACLE is 30 years old sir. I think it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Most likely DrNerj meant SQL*Developer 3 (the current major revision).

Answer (score 5):

I'll be lazy and show you one way to do this using `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT  ID,
        NAME,
        COUNTRY,
        STATE,
        DATE,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Red' THEN AMOUNT END) RED,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Blue' THEN AMOUNT END) BLUE,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Black' THEN AMOUNT END) Black,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE NOT IN ('Red','Blue','Black') THEN AMOUNT END) OTHER
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID,
         NAME,
         COUNTRY,
         STATE,
         DATE
```

I'm sure that when you specify the RDBMS, there will be at least one far more complete answer with different ways to do this.

Comment: I would suggest `sum` as the aggregate. Here is a demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d08d1/4

Comment: @bluefeet I thought about it, but decided to assume that there was only one row for each type. And now  realized that it wouldn't work for the `OTHER` column. I'm an idiot, but still waiting op to update his question so I can see your more complete answer :-)

Comment: @Lamak Thank you very much, that was very helpful. That method seems to work quite well. I would upvote your post, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @DrNerj You might not have the rep to upvote, but be sure to accept this answer if it solved your problem.